# Should I Split WP database? (Single WP running based on multiple Database)?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm going to a startup project which has almost 1 Million+ contents. Each content will be 350 words+/-. I planned with Advanced Custom Field, but after publishing 100K posts test based, my database size increased to 1.5GB!

Is there any option to Split my database or Running Single WP based on Multiple databases?

Or, any other solution, plz?

Noted:

I also tried bootstrap instead of Custom Field. Result: Site Speed is well, DB size 700MB. No media file used. But, worried about Million posts.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, wordpress site performance doesn't depends on database size. Where I am currently working, we have a wordpress project which database size 8GB+  , other media and files size around 65GB+.That site takes average 2 seconds to load any page.

So, how did we optimize that site ? We have been optimizing **query** those fetch data from database since database getting bigger. We cut off all time and resource consuming query to small chunk. And we have been using strict **caching** which makes our big site load time faster.

In conclusion, whatever site database size to increase performance you have to eliminate big query and cache as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, relational databases like MySQL are able to manage much more than 1.5 GB. I wouldn't worry about the performance of database sizes containing tens of GBs.

Comment: M. Mayer I just published 100K posts on test-based without any media files, just text. but, DB size 1.5K. So, how can I publish 1 Million? In fact, have to think about Speed issue as well.

Comment: How do you calculate the size? Depending on the  method you calculate the size MySQL parameters could influence your DB size.